# QSplitter - change the color of the grabbable area to make it more visible

Tags: qt

With QSplitter it is sometimes difficult to see whether there is a "grabbable" area and where to click in order to grab it.

I'd like to set the color of the grabbale area to something different to the background so it is visible.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, use `handle` selector:

```
QSplitter::handle {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, svlasov.  Is that Qt Quick?  I guess I should have said my app is a Qt widgets application.

Comment: This is Qt Stylesheet. Use it like `mainWindow->setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle{background: red;}");`.

Comment: Thank you.  There are so many ways of doing things in Qt!  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

### Method one: use palette

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui

app = QtWidgets.QApplication()

window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(window)
splitter.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello", splitter))
splitter.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("World", splitter))

window.setCentralWidget(splitter)
palette = window.palette()
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ColorRole.Window, QtGui.QColor("gray"))
window.setPalette(palette)

for handle in window.findChildren(QtWidgets.QSplitterHandle):
    palette = handle.palette()
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ColorRole.Window, QtGui.QColor("yellow"))
    handle.setPalette(palette)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

### Method two: use stylesheet

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui

app = QtWidgets.QApplication()

window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(window)
splitter.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello", splitter))
splitter.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("World", splitter))

window.setCentralWidget(splitter)
palette = window.palette()
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ColorRole.Window, QtGui.QColor("gray"))
window.setPalette(palette)

window.setStyleSheet("QSplitterHandle { background: red }")

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

### Note: do not use `QSplitter::handle` if you are using `QPalette`

`QSplitter::handle` will invalidate all `QSplitter`'s palette settings, and all children in `QSplitter`